# Value of datetime is always nil

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I got this problem. When I used rails console and execute this command @partner = Partner.find(1). the field lastStatement is nil but when 
I query using psql lastStatement value is 2013-07-14 13:40:07. I notice all dates value is nil in rails but in psql they have value. 
Any idea what is the problem? I am using rails 4 and posgresql 9

@partner = Partner.find(1)

Partner id: 1, name: "BPI", status: "online", tries: 5, lastStatement: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil

```
SELECT "partners".* FROM "partners" WHERE "partners"."id" = 1;

id | name | status | tries |    lastStatement    |        created_at         |    updated_at         
 1 | BPI  | online |     5 | 2013-07-14 13:40:07 | 2013-07-14 13:32:26.51822 | 2013-07-14 13:40:13.007967
```

Comment: Code from your model definition would be useful to help understand your problem,

Comment: are you inserting these date values directly in psql? or is it coming from your rails app? if it is the second case, try to reformat the date with Date.strptime("yyyy/mm/dd", "%m/%d/%y") before inserting into database

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the problem its about timezone. What I did to solve the problem is
change this value in my application.rb

```
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
config.active_record.time_zone_aware_attributes = false
```